# Using ADO and Edge - Cannot type in ticket fields

Tags: google-chrome, azure-devops, microsoft-edge

Using Azure DevOps and Microsoft Edge

Typing a ticket description, AC, or comment is impossible when using Edge as the browser. I start to type then the cursor starts behaving very weirdly and moving my typing location around in the text box making it impossible to type anything readable and/or English.

I do not have this issue when I use Chrome.

Any thoughts as to what is causing this in Edge?

Not sure where to even begin with this one

Comment: I have some questions: 1. Does it only occur in Azure DevOps and not in other types of textboxes? 2. What is your OS? (Windows 10 version 1511 has been reported to have such issue) Since it only occurs in Edge, I suggest trying the following methods: 1. Try Edge InPrivate mode. 2. Try re-installing Edge.

Comment: 1. Yes, Only in ADO that I have noticed so far.
2. 10.0.19044

I will try your two suggestions. Anything else would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I got it. You can also perform a test in another environment (another pc) if possible, just to rule out the possibility that some settings on your pc caused this problem.

Comment: Typing appears to work in InPrivate Mode.
Any ideas why not in the regular window?

Comment: Browsing InPrivate sort of equals to clearing your cookies and site data, and extensions won't be allowed to work unless you give permissions. You can try to clear your cookies and data in the regular Edge window and disable the extensions, if any, that may cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Edge. When I start typing in a comment box in ADO (hosted), if I press the letter 'a' I get 'has'. I've turned off predictive text and obvious tools that may cause this, so in the meantime have switched back to Chrome.